# Formula or script to achieve this?

Tags: excel, formula

What I want to achieve is something like that:

1. Check **IF** value of cell **A1 exist in array**.
2. If exist get the **"Defult" value** of the **Column**, if not exist the "Not in the list" .

I tried HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP but are limited to a single Row / Column at a time :(

[Look image at this link (i cant post images :/)](http://postimg.org/image/4kvzo7wpd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is very similar to a thread found at this link: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/673515-finding-value-multiple-column-array-returning-column-header-excel-2003-a.html

Regarding your specific version of this problem, here is a formula that will work.  Note that the formula in `B1` is an array formula and must be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

The idea for the formula is this:

1. Iterate through the array and look for a match to the cell in A1.
2. If there is a match, log the column of that match (in an array since this is an array formula). This is the logic using `COLUMN`.
3. Once all the cells in the array are checked, pick the largest column value returned using `MAX`.
4. Now with the correct column, return the column header using `INDEX`.

Because of #3, if there are duplicates, you will only get the one from the largest column.

```
=INDEX($E$1:$G$1,MAX(IF($E$3:$G$6=A1,COLUMN($E$3:$G$6)-COLUMN($E$1)+1)))
(this is an array formula that must be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)
```

That formula can be safely copied down in column B.

[image: formula and layout]

Same image with cells colored.

[image: formula and layout colored]

**If you want this formula to work when there are not matches, it needs to be modified slightly.**  You need to split out the array formula from the `INDEX` call.  The problem is that with no matches, `MAX` returns 0.  Normally `INDEX` will balk at a 0 except that in an array formula it appears to return the first value.  In that case, two formulas are needed, the first is an array formula, the second is a normal one.

```
[B1, array formula]  =MAX(IF($E$3:$G$6=A1,COLUMN($E$3:$G$6)-COLUMN($E$1)+1))
[C1, normal]  =INDEX($E$1:$G$1,B1)
```

With these, you will get `#VALUE!` on a missing search.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a different layout for the default values, to make it easy to use VLOOKUP. Instead of having one column for each person that have multiple spellings of their name, make a table with just two columns. The left column is the alternate spelling, the right column is what you want instead.

In your example "John Smith" has 3 alternate spellings. This would translate into three rows each with "John Smith" in the right column.